How to add a oklch color to tailwind safelist
I am trying to an a color from daisyUI to tailwind safelist but it does not seem to be working
tailwind.config.ts
const config: Config = {
  safelist: [
    'bg-[oklch(94.51% 0.179 104.32)]', // cyberpunk
  ],

}

and I am trying to use it like:
page.tsx
export default async function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="bg-[oklch(94.51% 0.179 104.32)]">
      page content...
    </main>
  );
}


But it is not working.

If you are using it in page.tsx and this file is covered by the content file globs in the Tailwind configuration, you do not need to add it to the safelist. Instead, you'd need to escape the spaces with underscores (_) for Tailwind to generate the appropriate CSS rule:
<main className="bg-[oklch(94.51%_0.179_104.32)]">

Or if page.tsx is not covered by the content file globs, then in safelist:
const config: Config = {
  safelist: [
    'bg-[oklch(94.51%_0.179_104.32)]', // cyberpunk


that works like a charm, Thank you so much! The above is actually a simplified case. I am actually creating a theme selector and want to show the theme colors. So I have to get all the daisyUI themes and map over the Object keys in js. As aresult I needed to do something like this in code: const bgColor = bg-[${themes[theme]['base-100'].replace(/ /g, '_')}];
